# How do I calculate tilt-compensated yaw?

Tags: java, math, sensors, euler-angles

I've been struggling for some time now on how to correctly calculate the yaw angle from an IMU, but can't get it to work. I'm using the LSM9DS1, if that matters.

I already have proper values for roll and pitch. The value for yaw is also more or less correct until I start tilting the device. Therefore I have to implement some kind of tilt compensation.

I calculate the euler angles as follows:

```
    double weight = 0.05f;

    private void calculateEulerAngles() {
        // Measured angle by the accelerometer
        double rollXLMeasured = Math.atan2(this.accelerometer.getX(), this.accelerometer.getZ()) / 2 / Math.PI * 360;
        double pitchXLMeasured = Math.atan2(this.accelerometer.getY() / 9.81f, this.accelerometer.getZ() / 9.81f) / 2 / Math.PI * 360;

        // Adding a low pass filter
        double rollXLFiltered = (1 - this.weight) * rollXLFilteredOld + this.weight * rollXLMeasured;
        double pitchXLFiltered = (1 - this.weight) * pitchXLFilteredOld + this.weight * pitchXLMeasured;
        this.rollXLFilteredOld = rollXLFiltered;
        this.pitchXLFilteredOld = pitchXLFiltered;

        // Calculating deltaTime
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        int difference = (int) ((time - this.deltaTime) / 1000000000);
        this.deltaTime = time;

        // Adding a complementary filter
        this.roll = ((1 - this.weight) * (this.roll + this.gyroscope.getY() * difference)) + (this.weight * rollXLMeasured);
        this.pitch = ((1 - this.weight) * (this.pitch - this.gyroscope.getX() * difference)) + (this.weight * pitchXLMeasured);

        // Calculating yaw using the magnetometer and applying a low pass filter
        double rollRadians = this.roll / 360 * (2 * Math.PI);
        double pitchRadians = this.pitch / 360 * (2 * Math.PI);
        double magnetometerXCompensated = (-this.magnetometer.getX() * Math.cos(rollRadians)) - (this.magnetometer.getY() * Math.sin(pitchRadians) *
                Math.sin(rollRadians)) + (this.magnetometer.getZ() * Math.cos(pitchRadians) * Math.sin(rollRadians));
        double magnetometerYCompensated = (this.magnetometer.getY() * Math.cos(pitchRadians)) + (this.magnetometer.getZ() * Math.sin(pitchRadians));
        double yawMeasured = Math.atan2(magnetometerYCompensated, magnetometerXCompensated) / (2 * Math.PI) * 360;
        double yawFiltered = (1 - this.weight) * yawFilteredOld + this.weight * yawMeasured;
        this.yawFilteredOld = yawFiltered;
        this.yaw = yawFiltered;

        // Print roll, pitch and yaw for debug purposes
        System.out.println(this.roll + ", " + this.pitch + ", " + this.yaw);
    }
```

I don't include the whole code I use, since I think it's clear what the above code does and this is the part thats essential to the problem, I suppose.

And again, I get correct values, just not for yaw when I tilt the device. So there has to be an error concerning the math.

Do I have to do my calculations with the raw values, like the data thats inside the IMU, or use already processed data? For example `this.accelerometer.getX()` actually returns `x_raw * 0.061f / 1000 * 9.81f` with `x_raw` being the value stored inside the IMU and `0.061f` being some coeffiecent. I basically copied the calculation from the Adafruit library, I'm not 100% sure why you have to multiply/divide those values though.

Also, you might have noticed that when I calculate the `magnetometerXCompensated` value I invert the x-axis. I do this, because the magnetometer axis aren't aligned with the acceleromter/gyroscope axis, so in order to align them I have to flip the x-axis.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? I'm really tired of it not working properly, since I tried for quite a while now to solve it, but I'm not getting the results I wanted.

Comment: Also, I do calibrate my magnetometer, since thats a common source for resulting in wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the equations from the next picture. The complimentary/Kalman filter is there in order to get less noise.
[image: Calculate Eulers angles from sensors]